# Import PGP public key by string

Tags: shell, gpgpu, pgp

I want to import a PGP public key into my keychain in a script, but I don't want it to write the contents to a file. Right now my script does this:

```
curl http://example.com/pgp-public-key -o /tmp/pgp && gpg --import /tmp/gpg
```

How could I write this script so I can just call `gpg --import` and import the public key as a string? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`gpg --import`  knows two ways of operation: it can either read from a file (for example `gpg --import key.gpg`) or -- if no file name is passed -- read from STDIN. `curl` on the other hand will print the fetched document to STDOUT if no `-o` parameter is given. Putting both together with a pipe will directly stream the results from `curl` into `gpg --import`:

```
curl http://example.com/pgp-public-key | gpg --import
```

Comment: Add `-L` to curl if you need it to follow redirects.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can use:

```
gpg --import <(curl http://example.com/pgp-public-key)
```

This is called [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `curl` to search for a key from a public keyserver if you know the key's ID:

```
curl -fsSL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=<key-id-here>" | gpg --import -
```

Note: you must prepend the key ID with `0x`.

Most public key servers allow you to truncate the key ID so you don't need to type the whole thing. For example, the following three examples will produce the exact same key:

```
curl -fsSL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0x9454C19A66B920C83DDF696E07C8CCAFCE49F8C5" | gpg --import -

curl -fsSL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0x07C8CCAFCE49F8C5" | gpg --import -

curl -fsSL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&search=0xCE49F8C5" | gpg --import -
```

Most of the key servers are synchronized too , so you don't necessarily need to stick with a single key server. You can see a list of other key servers and the information at the SKS Keyserver [status page](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/).

Explanations for the `-fsSL` in the `curl` command:

[`-f`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-f), [`--fail`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--fail):

> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors.

[`-s`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-s), [`--silent`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--silent):

> Silent or quiet mode.

[`-S`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-S), [`--show-error`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--show-error):

> When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it fails.

[`-L`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L), [`--location`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--location):

> (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place.

Answer (score 0):

We can also achieve this with pgp cmd. For example:

To import PGP public key to keychain(keyring):

```
pgp --import "F:\file_path\pgp_public_cert\publickey.asc" --public-keyring "F:\FilePath\keychain\pubchain.gpg"
```

To import PGP private key to keychain(keyring):

```
pgp --import "F:\file_path\pgp_private_cert\privatekey.asc" --private-keyring "F:\FilePath\keychain\secchain.gpg"
```

*Here,*

**publickey.asc**  ->  my public key

**privatekey.asc** ->  my private key

**pubchain.gpg**  ->  my public keyring/keychain where i have stored all my public certificate or public keys.

**secchain.gpg**  ->  my private keyring/keychain where i have stored all my private certificate or private keys.

Hope this also helps for somebody.